# What is the type of the reference held by the superclass reference variable?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Say I have two classes defined, `Super` and `Sub`, and `Sub` is a subclass of `Super`:

```
public class Super {}
public class Sub extends Super {}
```

I know that it is legal to do the following:

```
Super s = new Sub();
```

My question, though, is what does the compiler think the reference held in `s` is? Does it think it is just a reference of type `Super`, or does it know that it is actually a reference of type `Sub`. I've looked around for some answers to questions similar to this, but haven't found anything really definitive. Thank you!

Comment: Compiler thinka as Super only

Comment: No @Manishsakpal compiler is only aware about variable type that is Super. Not actual object

Comment: Yes @panther i know that the compiler is aware about only variable type is Super, but i forgot to mention that at runtime this s is refering to object of type Sub. Sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler may "know" for purposes of warning-messages that you have an instance of `Sub` (so, it might warn you if it sees you casting it to a different type, or unnecessarily checking if it's null), but in terms of what the language allows and forbids, the variable just has type `Super`.

(But at *runtime*, of course, the Java Virtual Machine will know that the instance has runtime-type `Sub`.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is the runtime type of `s` versus the compile time type of `s`. At compile time, it is considered a `Super`, as that is how it is declared in the code. However at runtime, it is treated as a `Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question, lets add some methods of our classes :-

```
public class Super {
        public void superMethod();
}
public class Sub extends Super {
        public void childMethod();
}
```

And if now we try to compile these below lines :-

```
Super s = new Sub();
s.superMethod();
s.childMethod();
```

In above code last line , will not compile as childMethod is not present in Class super but only in Sub. So, compiler is not compiling as it is referencing s as Sub.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler thinks of it only as `Super`.

Consider:

```
public class Super {}
public class Sub extends Super {
    void f() {}
}
```

Consider compiling the following code:

```
Super s = new Sub();

if (s instanceof Sub) {
    s.f();    // ERROR: will not compile!
}
```

Even though the compiler can tell that the type of `s` is being checked, and within the `if` block `s` must be of type `Sub` (or some descendant), it will still not treat `s` as a `Sub` without an explicit cast.

```
Super s = new Sub();

if (s instanceof Sub) {
    ((Sub)s).f();    // Now this compiles.
}
```